# Can't set backgroundColor property of UITableView in Attributes inspector after update to Xcode7-beta4

Tags: interface-builder, xcode7, ios9, xcode7-beta4

I'm trying to set `backgroundColor` property of `UITableView` with Interface Builder' Attributes Inspector after update to Xcode7-beta4 and it doesn't seem to work.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new single view project
2. Create `UITableViewController` with few static cells as initial controller of storyboard
3. Set `UITableView`'s background in Attributes inspector

It works if I set `backgroundColor` in User Defined Runtime Attributes.

Should I submit a bug report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved in Xcode7-beta5.